# How do I position my footer to absolutely bottom of screen

Tags: html, css

I have the following screen which uses a layout page. This view displays a card and apply the Layout page. How do I position the tags About, Services and Our Work to the bottom of the screen.

[image]

What I have tried:

```
<footer class="container space-1">
    <div class="row align-items-md-center text-center">
        @*<div class="col-md-3 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                <a href="#" aria-label="Front">
                    <img class="brand" src="https://template.tritonexpress.co.za/Images/Triton.png" alt="logo" width="120" />
                </a>
            </div>*@

        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-sm-0">
            <!-- Nav List -->
            <ul class="nav nav-sm nav-x-0 justify-content-center text-md-center">
                <li class="nav-item px-3">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-3">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-3">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our work</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- End Nav List -->
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3 text-sm-right">
            <!-- Social Networks -->
            <ul class="list-inline mb-0">
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-soft-secondary rounded-circle" href="#">
                        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-soft-secondary rounded-circle" href="#">
                        <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-soft-secondary rounded-circle" href="#">
                        <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-soft-secondary rounded-circle" href="#">
                        <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- End Social Networks -->
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Are you using a particular CSS framework (e.g. bootstrap, tailwindcss)?

Comment: @RobBailey I am using bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this :

```
<div class="footer fixed-bottom"></div>
```